# JAX-WS types element not shown

Tags: java, types, jax-ws

I'll try to make this question as clear as possible

I have a Java EAR project file with several JAX-WS web services.

Each web service has a  element that imports a schema XSD file.

If I access the wsdl file in the project the  element is present.

If I access the same wsdl from a client (browser) the  element isn't shown.

Anyone has any idea why this happens?

WSDL from project:

```
...
  // The following lines <types> ate miissing on the WSDL when accessed from the client (browser)
  <types>
    <xsd:schema>
      <xsd:import namespace="http://xxxxx.call/" schemaLocation="Callxxxxx_schema.xsd"/>
    </xsd:schema>
  </types>
  ...
  <service name="Call_xxxxxx">
    <port name="Call_xxxxxPort" binding="tns:Call_xxxxxPortBinding">
      <soap:address location="http://srv-can01-dev.teste.lab:9081/MyModule/Call_xxxxx"/>
    </port>
  </service>
  ...
```

(Same) WSDL from client:

```
...
  //<types> part missing when accessing from the client (browser)
  ...
  <service name="Call_xxxxx">
    <port name="Call_xxxxxPort" binding="tns:Call_xxxxxPortBinding">
      <soap:address location="http://machineIp:9081/MyModule/Call_xxxxx"/>
    </port>
  </service>
  ...
```

Comment: Please show an example of the wsdl viewed from the project and viewed from the client.

Comment: ok added the differences between the WSDL when accessed from the project and from a web browser

Comment: This is a browser independent problem, meaning that it occurs on any browser.

Comment: I give further explanation on the WSDL cretaion here:

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=14625184&

Comment: is your client on the same machine.

Comment: No, it isn't, but I already tried to call the Web Service from the same machine and the problem persists, no <types> so no schema is imported.

If I force the paramenters of the XSD on the operation call, I get the response correctly, but of course, what I wan't is those parameters to be asked, not guessed.

I also remind that I have the same version of the application installed on 3 other machines and don't have this problem.

Thanks again

Comment: On what server did you deploy the jax-ws webservice (weblogic/websphere/...)?

Answer (score 0):

@RedEagle: try few things and let me know result:-
i) Rename your .wsdl extn file to .xml file and open it with your browser. See if it appears fine.

ii) See the "View Source" from browser to check what is actually being received by browser.

iii) Make sure there is no surrounding html or XML based comment tags.

iv)lastly instead of `<xsd:import>,` define your XML elements/types with in WSDL file itself and see if it works.

Comment: i) Same problem

ii) Already had tried that. The types tag isn't present

iii) Not one

iv) it works but I have to do it manually for every wsdl and that's not what I want

Comment: @RedEagle: it is really quite strange issue. Anyways put your both wsdl file and schema Callxxxxx_schema.xsd in a window directory, and try to open in browser, see what happens. Tell me browser name and version. Lastly, if possible attach your whole wsdl and xsd file. I can try out on my machine.

Comment: If I open it directly from the folder, the <xsd:imports> tag is show on IE 7.

Sorry but I can't give you the files, but like I said, I already published the project that contains these files on 3 other machines, and they work correctly